# AJAX live search in dictionary from txt files?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dictionary, livesearch

I have files "a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt", ... Every file contain translation for words.
*English-Russian, it seems like:

able 'eibl способный

about x'baut приблизительно; о

above q'bAv над, выше*


Is it possible to realize live search in this dictionary just by AJAX (without PHP or something else) ? If possible, could you explain please? Some example will be very helpful.

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Sure it's possible. Go ahead and try it, we'll be glad to help if you get stuck on some errors. But no, AJAX is reliant on Client To Server communication, so you need PHP or some other server-side language to have an actual AJAX. But that doesn't mean you can't achieve the task without a server-side language, it simply means that AJAX isn't necessarily needed, you could just do the reading on the client side.

Comment: @Jonast92 Where do you think the .txt files are? I assume they're on a server, so yes, he would need some form of AJAX. AJAX has nothing to do with PHP or any other server side language.

Comment: @Adelphia, it's just training task, so files are on local storage.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference. You still need AJAX unless you're going to hard-code your definitions into the JS. As long as the files are located where ever the JS is located and the browser can access them.

Comment: @Adelphia 
"With Ajax, Web applications can send data to, and retrieve data from, a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page." Would you like to demonstrate what AJAX is if it's not about the communication between client and server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible. Anything's possible if you just believe!

Use your AJAX to call the txt file from your server, then use the `.search("some word");` method to find what you need.

This is an aweful solution though because the user will have to download the entire text file, and your client side code will have to parse the entire text to find what you're looking for.

You're much better off using PHP/MySQL.

Comment: I don't understand .search, I'm trying to do own function. But how to transfer data from opened file and data from textbox to other function?? <br/> function search(textBox) {
 var txt = textBox.value;
 $.get("dict/" + txt[0] + ".txt").success(parseResults);
}

function parseResults() {
}

Comment: Oh, I think I know. At least I get word from file.

Comment: Use node and mongodb, not php and MySQL long live JavaScript !

Comment: Humm, it works for me with just AJAX (except some problems with algorithm). It's learning task, so such method suit to me.